# Одинаковые стили для :hover и :focus

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Есть несколько элементов input. Задача при :hover и :focus задать им одинаковые стили. Мучаюсь уже несколько часов, все без толку. Если один input находится в фокусе, и при этом мы наводим на другой input, то стили у них отличаются, а именно - outline у :hover больше чем у :focus. С чем это связано и как решить эту проблемы. Вот фотография проблемы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] а вот образец кода:

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  outline: none;
}

input:hover,
input:focus {
  border-color: grey;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Нужно же, чтобы стили у них были абсолютно идентичны.

Comment: у меня одинаковые.http://joxi.ru/Grqe1g6Fwxkprz 

У тебя может быть еще стили прописаны к инпутам, отдельно где то

Comment: Нет, все стили, какие есть, написаны в примере кода.Браузер Google.

Comment: хром стави свои стили помимо Ваших, вот к примеру добавил на чистый хтмл без стилей инпут - и при фокусе он уже ссо стилями. Нужно в консольке браузера отловить какие стили Вам подставляются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже это из-за предустановленных стилей хрома (тестил в хроме и лисе, в лисе нормально).

Для хрома добавьте `outline-offset: 0px;`

Comment: @Animal, судя по всему Вы правы. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

у меня одинаковые.http://joxi.ru/Grqe1g6Fwxkprz

У тебя может быть еще стили прописаны к инпутам, отдельно где то.